# Accessing Redux Store in a Util file

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**TLDR:** I want to be able to grab the latest Redux State in an external "Util" file.  How can I do this?

---

Say I have a playlist.. and in many different areas of the app, you can "Start" the playlist.  So in a "Util" file I have the "startPlaylist" function so I dont have to write the function in numerous places but in only one place.

The problem with this, is that if I make any changes to the playlist while the playlist is running, "playNextPageInPlaylist" function will not receive any updates to the playlist.

What can I do and change so that my function(s) in the Util file will receive the most updated Redux State?

I have startPlaylist function in 7 different areas, and the functions it involves (all in the Util file) are quite complex.. and it wouldn't make sense to copy and paste that in all 7 files.

Thanks for any help

---

React.Component File 1

```
import { startPlaylist } from '../util/EntitiesUtil';

start1() {   
  startPlaylist( store.playlists[0] ); 
}
```

React.Component File 2

```
import { startPlaylist } from '../util/EntitiesUtil';

start2() {
  startPlaylist( store.playlists[0] );
}
```

EntitiesUtil.js

```
export function startPlaylist( playlistFromStore ) {
  // do stuff
  playNextPageInPlaylist( playlistFromStore );  // keeps grabbing next page on a timer
}
```

Comment: I am trying to make sense and I have this question: Util files should not fetch the state themselves. You should pass it the latest state from wherever you are using or alternatively, you could create "state selectors". Are you sure your state is updating? can you show me the code where you are changing the state?

Comment: yes, normally everything in the util, i pass in parts of the redux state as the parameter.  the thing is in my particular case.. since it's a revolving playlist.. it keeps playing the next page on a timer.. but it will only get the next page of the playlist (kept in the redux state) that i passed in as a parameter.  if i make any changes to the playlist.. it will not get that change in the endless loop of playing pages because it's only getting the redux state passed in (which is the old, un-updated state).  let me know if that doesnt' make sense.

Comment: Its getting too abstract. Timer, endless loop, playlist . I am losing you. 

Can you put your problem on codepen  ?

Comment: @MatthewBarbara i wish i could but it's a huge project unfortunately =T  but even if i did post the program with the timers and loop i dont think any of it is really relevant to what i need =T

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You got couple of options, the main options as i see it are:

1. pass the store to the function (bah please don't do that!).
2. You can write your own middleware that handles certain action types
   and can dispatch other actions if needed (you also get a free
   access to the **ENTIRE** store!).

I think the 2nd option is ideal, as you want your `util` to do stuff that reflect in the store or need stuff from the store. So basically your `util` wants to be a part of the `redux` flow!
Well it's not a `component` so you can't "connect" it but it can (and should be in my opinion) ad middleware that sits between your actions and reducers.

You can read about middlewares [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html).
I would have provided you an example of your use case but you didn't post any meaningful code.

**Edit**
A followup to your comment:

Its quite basic.

1. You have a signature of a function that never changes, just look at
   the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) (it uses
   [currying](https://medium.com/@kbrainwave/currying-in-javascript-ce6da2d324fe),
   this is another `js` topic you should learn)
2. You need to inject it to the store when you create it with
   `applymiddleware` (same as you did with `redux-thunk` which is a
   middleware by itself).

I realy recommend to look at the source code of `redux-thunk` [the whole 11 lines of it](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk/blob/master/src/index.js).
You can learn a lot from it.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. i am seeking how to do this properly so i will look into middleware..  i have an idea what middleware is but i'm not sure how i can apply it in my case, but i will look into it.  ty for the suggestion

Comment: think of it this way: if your `util` need to access or update the store it needs to be a part of the `redux` flow. to be part of the flow it needs to be either a `component`, an `action` / `thunk`, a `reducer` or a `middleware`.  did i miss one?

Comment: ah okay.. i think it makes sense.. i will tutorial how to create a middleware and hopefully figure out a solution

Comment: I was going to suggest you @Sag1v option 2 before I was digging deeper into your business logic. I would go for it.

Comment: just looked at your edit.. starting to read about middleware now.. i hope i can comprehend all this and create what i need.. i think i get the gist of it though.  ty again

Comment: @Sag1v is middleware still the way to go if i want to just access getState()?  I don't want to call any actions at all.. i just need to get the most up to date State.. and it seems like middleware is more for actions? getting a bit frustrated here =\

Comment: @user1189352 it is really up to you, as i see it (I've mentioned it in my answer) if my code block needs to be a part of the `redux` flow then it needs to be one of the participants: a component, an action, a reducer or a middle-ware. of course you can send the entire store somehow to the util function but why would you? for example, a util that gets the store and ajax it to the server (maybe a kind of a logger for example), you will need to write the call to the function- util everywhere. but if it's inside a middle-ware you can listen to all or some of the actions and do your stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `store` has a `getState(`) method available to you.

Import your created store and then call `store.getState()`

Check out this example from redux's main site:

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/Store.html#example

```
function select(state) {
  return state.some.deep.property
}

let currentValue
function handleChange() {
  let previousValue = currentValue
  currentValue = select(store.getState())

  if (previousValue !== currentValue) {
    console.log(
      'Some deep nested property changed from',
      previousValue,
      'to',
      currentValue
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: ah.. maybe.. i guess i gotta figure out where to get store in the template I'm using.. thank you for the suggestion will let you know if it works out https://github.com/coryhouse/react-slingshot

Comment: i've tried accessing it like suggested but it only returns the original, initial state when the program launches, and not all the changes to the state after load.  i'm thinking maybe i can get the main state somehow.. still searching the template to see

Comment: Well I think you need to just move the store.getState() call into the body of your utility functions. @user1189352

Comment: So that it doesn't get invoked until you want it to

Answer (score 0):

We faced a similar issue in using corporate ui react library where state creation was delegated to core library. Thus, exporting store as public variable was not an option to us.

However, there is a horrible way of 'public static variable' that will be updated with your root reducer or 'slicing reducers'.

so, you should make some 'store-util.tsx' with 'let utilStore' variable and export some setter (for reducer) and getter (for any utility functions) functions.